# dnsmasq, Android not receiveing address

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, dnsmasq

I'm having problems obtaining an address from dnsmasq on an Android phone.

I am running dnsmasq and hostapd on a Raspberry Pi.  Hostapd connection and handshake is working fine.  Running dnsmasq with debug switches returns:

```
Nov 19 13:10:26 dnsmasq-dhcp[3428]: DHCPDISCOVER(wlan0) d8:b3:77:00:00:00 
Nov 19 13:10:26 dnsmasq-dhcp[3428]: DHCPOFFER(wlan0) 192.168.69.204 d8:b3:77:00:00:00 
Nov 19 13:10:26 dnsmasq-dhcp[3428]: DHCPREQUEST(wlan0) 192.168.69.204 d8:b3:77:00:00:00 
Nov 19 13:10:26 dnsmasq-dhcp[3428]: DHCPACK(wlan0) 192.168.69.204 d8:b3:77:00:00:00 Android_A1000017000000
Nov 19 13:10:32 dnsmasq-dhcp[3428]: DHCPDISCOVER(wlan0) d8:b3:77:00:00:00
Nov 19 13:10:32 dnsmasq-dhcp[3428]: DHCPOFFER(wlan0) 192.168.69.204 d8:b3:77:00:00:00
.... forever ....
```

Run command:

```
 sudo dnsmasq -C network/dnsmasq.conf -d -q -8-
```

Config File:

```
domain-needed
bogus-priv
address=/double-click.net/127.0.0.1
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=192.168.69.33,192.168.69.254,12h
```

What am I missing that the Android wants?
Also, the first address served is 204?  that seems a little weird. (no other dhcp servers are running, I checked)

Comment: You need to see if you can get any sort of log from Android dhcp client. Things like that happen when client does not like address for some reason but does not send reject.

Comment: I wonder if sending default route as here might help: http://rudd-o.com/archives/wifi-dhcp-network-not-working-with-your-android-phone